# MySQL IN() statements: Avoiding duplicate lists

Tags: mysql

I need to check that two columns both appear in a list of IDs. So right now I have this:

```
SELECT 
    `main_table`.*
FROM
    `activities` AS `main_table`
WHERE
    (actor_id IN ('10027' , '11535'))
        AND (original_actor_id IN ('10027' , '11535'))
```

The problem is that the list of IDs can get pretty big; into the thousands. I can't find a way without another temp table that lets me check that two columns are in a list without defining the list twice. I'm concerned that it's an excessively large query to send back and forth from my PHP web server.

Comment: so the problem with this approach is only the package size?

Comment: That's the one that I'm worried about. However, anything suggestions to make these kinds of queries run faster when searching a long list multiple times would be appreciated.

Comment: U can make the size smaller by using a variable to hold the list. but if the list gets too large, you might pass the `max_allowed_packet`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temp table, insert your parameters there and then join it:

```
create temporary table tmp (x int);
insert into tmp(x) values (10027),(11535);
select x.* 
from activities as x 
join tmp as y 
    on y.x = x.actor_id
join tmp as z
    on z.x = x.original_actor_id;
```

Comment: The OP's query has `AND`. It should be 2 joins to the temp table.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I'll fix that when I get back to a computer.

Comment: Declaring a PK on tmp may help performance and insert in order of the the PK.